# Activity onResume: strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

For demonstrating the activity life cycle, I have added TextToSpeech messages

```
mTts.speak ("<some text>", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

to hear when I am going through `onCreate`, `onResume`, and `onPause`.

Findings:

In `onCreate`, you don't hear the text to be spoken (obviously because the activity has not yet resumed?).

In onPause, the text spoken was mutilated (obviously because of leaving the activity while the text is spoken?).

Building a loop

```
while(mTts.isSpeaking()){}
```

assured the text was completely spoken.

Much more strange is the behaviour in `onResume`:

- Starting the activity the text in `onResume` is not spoken.
- Pressing the HW Home button and opening the app again the text in onResume is spoken.

Of course `onResume` is executed in both cases. For the matter of fact I assigned a string

- in `onResume`: `speakOnResume` = "on resume"
- in `onCreate`: `speakOnCreate` = "on create"

and added an event callback to the activity where I called

```
mTts.speak (speakOnResume + " " + speakOnCreate, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

and of course the lady spoke as expected

Now the question:

Any idea, why `onResume` behaves differently when starting the activity from scratch v.s. when (in the word's sense) resuming it after it was paused without stopping/destroying?

Comment: 5 years and no answer so far??? I have a vary similar problem with the ImageViews in my layout not displaying properly only after onResume() has been called?